# How to add a navigation bar to UITabBarController?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

Im trying to add a navigation bar to all view controllers inside my tabbarcontroller.  Do I add the nav bar to individual view controllers...

or

Is there another way?

Comment: Yes, u can add a navigation bar to all view controllers inside u r tabbar controller.and also u can add the nav abr to individual view controllers.

code is also available.

Comment: ok but I tried adding the navbar to the uitabbarcontroller in storyboards and it doesnt work. The navbar bounces back out when i drop it in.  Zoomed in or out...